# .htaccess - Redirect subdomain to folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

This question has probably been asked for over a thousand times, but I've tried so many scripts, and googled so long while finding nothing, I thought, let's just ask.

I simply want `m.daltonempire.nl` to be redirected to `daltonempire.nl/m/` without the user seeing the URL change.

So if `m.daltonempire.nl/hello.php` is requested, I want the user to keep seeing this URL, while the page given is actually `daltonempire.nl/m/hello.php`.

*Note: I do not want `www.`, so simply `http://m.daltonempire.nl`*

Thanks in advance,

Isaiah v. Hunen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set CNAME of my sub domain below:

`blog.mydomain.com`

to my wordpress that installed in folder `/blog/` under root directory.

Formerly I need to use this url to call wordpress:

`http://blog.mydomain.com/blog/`

which is ugly. I have tried many code to redirect:

`http://blog.mydomain.com/`

to the folder so I can use it as my wordpress url.

Finally I got [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387850/4058484) setting that is work:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
    RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1
```

I have also CNAME other subdomain: `http://forum.mydomain.com` to mybb installation in folder `/forum/mybb/` so the `.htaccess` need to put `[L]` on each of RewriteRule code as below.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.tophyips\.info$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/mybb/
    RewriteRule (.*) /forum/mybb/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.tophyips\.info$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
    RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1 [L]
```

In case you want to use the code please don't forget to set the site url and cookie path in the application config file follow to the setting to make the redirection work properly.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.daltonempire\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m(/|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [L]
```

The `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` conditions would let you access `/exists.php` and not rewrite it to `/m/exists.php`. Remove those two if you want to rewrite even if that may potentially override existing files and directories.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I've almost given up on this whole rewrite thing, been trying ~10 different ways of doing it and every other way gave me 500 error.

Comment: @kK-Storm Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal can't thank you enough. Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Try this example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://example.com/%1" [L,P]
```

Any requests `http://test.example.com` will be mapped to `http://example.com/test/...`

Try googling `dynamic subdomain with php and htaccess` to get better search results.

Comment: 1 year later and when I try Googling `dynamic subdomain with php and htaccess` I find this question...

Comment: @Latheesan caused an infinite loop

Comment: But it doesnt work for me.  Even after correcting it.  The fullstop in the square brackets should be escaped, and perhaps the slash too