# Run multiple domains under 1 wordpress instance

Tags: wordpress

I have a question. I am trying to set up two domains under one wordpress instance.

For instance, I have a wordpress site on www.site1.com

I have another domain called www.site2.com. Now, I want to run the same wordpress site that is under www.site1.com on www.site2.com

I tried using the wordpress domain mu mapping plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/

But it only allows me subdomains or directories of www.site1.com

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question... try the wordpress stack exchange.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

to wp-config.php.

Comment: You mean wp-config.php :)

Answer (score 0):

If you meant pointing 2 or more domain names to a single wordpress install, answer is yes you can but it won't work. Wordpress is designed only to host one domain name, if you point another domain name to your wordpress, it will return 404. The other way around to do this is redirect your other domain names to your main domain name (i.e. redirect website2.com to website1.com)

If you meant pointing 2 or more domain names to a Wordpress Multi site install, here's an article that will help you setting up domain mapping in your Wordpress multisite: https://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/multisite/domain-mappinng/

Answer (score 0):

We need to set [WordPress Multisite Network](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/creating-wordpress-multisite-network-nginx/) to make it work. I have successfully set my wordpress v4.1 installation to work for [multiple sites and multiple domains](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-domain-with-multisite) by following [*this*](https://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/multisite/domain-mappinng/) and [*this*](http://resources.kevinspence.org/multiple-domains-on-wordpress/).

Please note that you will have to make sure editing to php files correctly otherwise that will completely crash your site if you make a mistake. Moreover a correct setting of [*htaccess*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29363720/4058484) is also important.