# Redirect all subdomain urls to subdirectory urls .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all URL on nz subdomain to nz directory now.

Example scenarios:

Redirect `nz.domain.com` to `domain.com/nz`

Redirect `nz.domain.com/any-url` to `domain.com/nz/any-url`

I have already tried [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory) and [.htaccess - Redirect subdomain to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663849/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-folder) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nz\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^nz/ /nz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Doesn't work - website has a redirect loop and then this happens test url - `nz.domain.com/bp-release/` goes to `http://nz.domain.com/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/nz/bp-release/`

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work. It goes into the first directory somehow. - `http://nz.domain.com/nz/framework/main.php?url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/framework/main.php&url=/nz/bp-release/`

Comment: Last comment for tonight as it is awfully late. Make sure to keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line and test  after clearing browser cache