# htaccess remove subdomain in referal links

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to change urls like this:
**blog.example.com/blog/tag/exampletag**
to this:
**example.com/blog/tag/exampletag**

what htaccess code should I use? my blog is using **wordpress**

"the first style refers to my old blog and comes from google and visitors face to 500 server errors"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

Comment: Another Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663849/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-folder