# Rewrite url to subdomain (Codeigniter with htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a question about my htaccess and codeigniter,  I've been experimenting with my HTACCESS for a while.
I want to rewrite a specific url(with its parameters) to specific subdomain, for example:

```
example.com/member/*
```

to:

```
member.example.com/*
```

my `htaccess` currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^example\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule /member/(.*)     "http://member.example.com/$1"

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in htaccess to rewrite subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On

 #If the host is "sub.domain.com"
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
 #Then rewrite any request to /folder
 RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Here, Replace **sub.domain.com** with your subdomain name and **folder** with the name of your folder you want to point your subdomain to.

Comment: hi and thanks, didnt worked for me, browser returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Please follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663849/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-folder