# Route to admin page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, admin, routes

I'm working with Codeigniter and i want to have a URL like this:

`admin.domain.com`

And then route it to the real controller and function.

It means I don't want to have a URL like this : `www.domain.com/admin`.

I have one controller for back-end and another for front.

This is my default controller in route file:

```
  $route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

so how should i do it? with route file or htaccess file or some another way?!

Comment: I think the answer you look for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513222/subdomains-leading-to-codeigniter-controllers/22051000#22051000

Comment: i put this code in route file but didnt work in my case:      switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
    case 'students.mysite.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "students";
    break;
    case 'teachers.mysite.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "teachers";
    default:
        // The list of your $routes lines at is was...
    break;
}

Comment: im testing on localhost and change it to this:                                                                     switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
    case 'admin.mysite/':
        $route['default_controller'] = "backend";
    break;
    case 'mysite/':
        $route['default_controller'] = "home";
        $route['404_override'] = '';
    break;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subdomains leading to Codeigniter Controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513222/subdomains-leading-to-codeigniter-controllers)