# How to use dynamic subdomain using Codeigniter - CPanel wild card subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently using CodeIgniter 3. I want to create dynamic subdomains like team1.domain.com, team2.domain.com, etc.

These domains need to point to the controller Team and a specifically to the `show_Team` method in the that controller.

```
--------------------------------------------
$route['team/(:any)'] = "Team/show_Team"; 
--------------------------------------------
```

I had severall rules in the .htaccess, but these do a redirect to `/team/team1`, but I want to work from the subdomain.

Like as said team1.domain.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513222/subdomains-leading-to-codeigniter-controllers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subdomains leading to Codeigniter Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513222/subdomains-leading-to-codeigniter-controllers)